# Dynamically call router function

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

I am trying to create a way in which I can register routes extremely easily without having to actually do `app.get('/', function (req, res, next) { });` and it'll do this automatically for me from a router object I pass in like the following...

```
{ 
    path: '',
    method: 'GET',
    function: 'test'
}
```

Now, everything is working okay up until the point it actually calls the function.

The issue lies with the way in which I am calling this function as it doesn't actually call the function it just references it.

This is the code that calls it.

```
this.routes.forEach((route: IRouter) => {
    const path = this.basePath + '/' + route.path;
    const requestMethod = route.method.toLowerCase();

    this.app[requestMethod](path, this[route.function]());
});
```

So you can see at the end of the `this.app` line, I am calling the function however I aren't actually passing in any of the required params such as `res, req, next`.

Is there a way from Express where I can get access to it from the app as I have the app instance. Removing the `()` from the end of the function line as stated earlier just references the function and doesn't call it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you meant to call `this[route.function]` rather than passing a reference to it? (i.e. remove the `()` after it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work depending on what `this[route.function]()` returns. For example, if the `test` function was like:

```
test () {
    return (req, res, next) => {...}
}
```

Then I don't see why it wouldn't work. If it's like this:

```
test (req, res, next) {...}
```

Then you should execute the function when adding the route handler. Unless you are going to be passing things to the functions, I would go with the 2nd test function without executing it so you'd have:

```
class Foo () {
  constructor (config) {
    const { basePath } = this

    this.routes.forEach((route: IRouter) => {
      const path = `${basePath}/${route.path}`
      const requestMethod = route.method.toLowerCase()

     this.app[ requestMethod ](path, this[ route.function ].bind(this))
    })
  }

  test (req, res, next) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This way you aren't creating an unnecessary function.

Also, instead of using `function` in your route object, I'd use `fn` so that you don't use a reserved keyword. It'll work but it can run you into issues and just a good idea to not use those.